# How to check if whether a file has extension pdf or not?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a method for uploading files. And I want to check if the uploaded file is a pdf file.

So I try it like this:

```
def post(self, request):
        submitted_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        content = ''

        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            uploadfile = UploadFile(image=request.FILES["upload_file"])

            file_extension = os.path.splitext(uploadfile[1])

            if file_extension in {'pdf'}:
                print('Is pdf')

            uploadfile.save()

            with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                                   f"{uploadfile.image}"), 'r') as f:

                content = f.read()

            print(content)

            return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
                'form': ProfileForm(),
                "content": content
            })

        return render(request, "main/create_profile.html", {
            "form": submitted_form,
        })
```

But then I get this error:

```
TypeError at /

'UploadFile' object is not subscriptable
```

Question: what I have to change?

Comment: `if upload.name.endswith(".pdf")`

Comment: Try `uploadfile = UploadFile(image=(request.FILES["upload_file"]))` if `request.FILES` is a dictionary

Comment: What I can try? Sorry don't understand. also upload.name? I don't have a upload variable.

Comment: If you had checked the documentation on the `UploadFile` object, you'd see that you need `uploadfile.name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.endswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=endswith#str.endswith) as stated by [@TomMcLean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14720380/tom-mclean) in above comment, so:

At first, typecast file name into `str` then apply `str.endswith()` on it as the method only works on string type.

Attach following code in the view:

```py
name_of_file = str(request.FILES['upload_file'])
print("Now its type is ", type(name_of_file))
if name_of_file.endswith('.pdf'):
    print('It is .pdf')
else:
    print('It is .txt')
```

Use it like this in the view:

```py
class CreateProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        form = ProfileForm()
        return render(request, "home/create_profile.html", {
            "form": form
        })

    def post(self, request):
        submitted_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        content = ''

        if submitted_form.is_valid():
            uploadfile = UploadFile(image=request.FILES["upload_file"])
            name_of_file = str(request.FILES['upload_file'])
            print("Now its type is ", type(name_of_file))
            if name_of_file.endswith('.pdf'):
                print('It is .pdf')
            else:
                print('It is .txt')
            uploadfile.save()
            with open(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                                   f"{uploadfile.image}"), 'r') as f:
                content = f.read()

            print(content)
            return render(request, "home/create_profile.html", {
                'form': ProfileForm(),
                "content": content
            })

        return render(request, "home/create_profile.html", {
            "form": submitted_form,
        })
```